# Odd infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I was looking at another question where the user submitted some code that was seg-faulting.
This code had a loop that tried writing to an array index that was out of bounds, and as part of my examining the code, I tried compiling and running it.  (The OP was reporting that it was writing to a file - something that was only in the code long after the out of bounds loop).

I added in some `printf()` statements (yes, I know, C++, use `std::cout`, but I was keeping to what *they* had used) to keep track of progress at runtime, then I compiled and ran it.

I got no output.

This was odd, so I cut out all but the loop in question.  This is the exact code I then ran:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

#define m 17
#define n 17
using namespace std;


int main(){
    double f0[n][m],f[n][m],x[n],y[m];
    double dx, time, dy, dt, alpha, mstep, termx, termy, dd;
    dx = 1.0;
    dy = 1.0;
    dt = 0.20;
    alpha = 0.20;
    mstep = 200;
    FILE * mFile;

    for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
        printf("running: j = %d\n",j);    //***                          I added this line
        for(int i=0; i<n+1; i++){
            f0[i][j] = 0.0;
            f[i][j] = 0.0;
            if (i == n && j == m-1){ printf("Will this crash now?\n");}//I added this line
        }
    }
    printf("made it out without crashing");                            //I added this line


    return 0;   
}
```

I was expecting the following output (the line commented with `***` wasn't present at this point:

```
Will this crash now?
Segmentation-fault... (blah blah blah)
```

Instead, there was nothing, and control was not released.
Adding in the `***` line, I then ran the program again:

```
...
running: j = 1
running: j = 2
running: j = 3
running: j = 4
running: j = 5
running: j = 1
running: j = 2
running: j = 3
running: j = 4
running: j = 5
running: j = 1
...
```

This is odd.  There should be no allocations to `j` beyond the `j++` in the for-loop header, yet it was being reset at some point.

I compiled and ran this a number of times in case it was a glitch, with no change. I then ran the entire code as originally posted in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714862/c-segmentation-faultcore-dumped), but with my extra `printf` statements added.
The `j` cycle now went from 1 to 15.

Further testing showed that the length of the code is somehow changing the period of the cycle.

```
The code posted in this question: 33 lines, 1- 5 repeated.
The original code posted:         98 lines, 1-15 repeated.
Removing bottom two loops:        71 lines, 1-10 repeated.
```

Is this a compiler error somehow or am I being blind and doing some allocation to `j` somewhere and totally missing it?

Can anyone even reproduce this?

Compiler: GCC 4.8.2 running under Cygwin.

Comment: `i<n+1` could get well out of bounds for `f[i][j]`, though there's not necessarily a _'crash'_. It's simply calling for undefined behavior.

Comment: _"I'm aware of that.."_ I'm afraid at least not of the whole story.

Comment: idiot moment by me, the inner loop of course goes out of bounds on each outer loop...  Flagged to close.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that out-of-bounds access will happen only after `i == n && j == m-1` according to your check, but in fact it will happen much earlier. The first time out-of-bounds access happens is when `j==0 && i==n`. After that, all bets are off. The program might crash, enter an infinite loop, or do something else.

Answer (score 2):

This loop is almost certainly wrong:

```
    for(int i=0; i<n+1; i++){
       f0[i][j] = 0.0;
        f[i][j] = 0.0;
```

since the major dimension is `n` and you are therefore iterating beyond the array bounds.

You either want:

```
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
```

or you need to make the array dimension larger by 1.

Otherwise undefined behaviour is just that - undefined.

Comment: "This code had a loop that tried writing to an array index that was out of bounds"

Comment: I think that's the point of the question - he's doing it on purpose.

Comment: Oh - my bad - so the question boils down to "why doesn't undefined behaviour do what I want?" ?

Comment: @PaulR Think so yes.

Comment: no, it boils down to "why doesn't it even get to the undefined behaviour?"  And possibly more interesting: "why when I change the source code size does the length of the cycle change? "

Comment: @Baldrickk How will you know, that no UB was called?

Comment: bleh, slight brain flatulence on my part - when I wrote the code I forgot that the inner loop will go out of bounds on each iteration of j...